# Is there any DB index that can improve the performance of 'like %keyword%' queries?

Tags: sql, database, web, sql-like

I know indexing on a text field can help with searches with `like 'keyword%'`.

But is there any cross-database indexing that can improve full text search with `like '%keyword%'`?

And generally, for a text fields with less than 1000 chars, when does the performance of `like %keyword%` query becomes unacceptable for a web request? Say when the table reaches 10K rows?

Comment: Postgres can use an index for `like '%keyword%'`: http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/  not sure what you mean with "cross-database indexing" though.

Comment: I mean an index that can be created in standard SQL supported by all dbs.

Comment: Most DBMS support a built-in full text search as a fast alternative to `LIKE` - but the syntax is different for each DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FULLTEXT INDEX and seach using specific commands - on MSSQL could use   CONTAINS(column, '* keyword *') or FREETEXT - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

Regarding your question about performance, it's strongly linked to your infrastructure, your data or your search terms.